# Performing Oracle Text search on column with xml and html tags

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-text

I've done some online reading but can't seem to find an answer to what I'm looking for. It may be because I'm approaching this the wrong way. 
I am using Oracle 10g.

I have table xyz with columns:

```
recID-   VARCHAR type

XML- CLOB type
```

The XML column contains xml and html tags. ie.

```
<Employee><firstName>John</firstName>
<EmpDesc><![CDATA[<p>I like to live by Ghandi&#39s motto: Be the <strong>change</strong> you want to see</p>]]</EmpDesc>
</Employee>
```

An index was created:

```
create index myIndex on xyz(xml) indextype is ctxsys.context
```

When I perform the query below, I don't get the result I'm expecting, because one of the words is enclosed in html tags.

```
SELECT * from xyz where contains(xml, 'be the change you want to see')>0;
```

*Note that the string can exist in any node so inpath may not be a suitable option.

Is there a way to create an index to ignore html tags so that a result is returned?

Comment: I'm not aware of any indexing (option) to ignore the html. But I'm not too deep into this topic. In lieu of it, and depending on the overall requirements, I'd probably think of using an html stripped away column. Perhaps employing `str_html` from [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:769425837805). (Which I've seen referenced elsewhere, but never used myself.)

Comment: Alternatively, you might want to try along `SELECT * from xyz where REGEXP_LIKE(xml, REGEXP_REPLACE('be the change you want to see', '.+'), 'in');`. A bit more restrictive: `SELECT * from xyz where REGEXP_LIKE(xml, REGEXP_REPLACE('be the change you want to see', '.{1,10}'), 'in');` Here the second parameter in the curly brackets would need to be high enough a number to allow for the maximum length of accepted (sequences of) tags plus whitespace surrounding them.